# How do I keep track of directories being created during installation of PostgreSQL?

Tags: directory, delete, postgresql, software-uninstall

I want to install PostgreSQL (on a server that runs Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS) using the source code distribution as per instructions in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/installation.html.

The instructions tell me that if I want to undo the installation at a later date (for whatever reason) I can do so with make uninstall but that I have to bear in mind that this will not remove any directories that were created during the installation.

What is the easiest way to keep track of all the new directories that were created during the installation? Something along the lines of:

- Here is a list of all directories (and subdirectories) prior to the installation (`tree` possibly?).
- Here is a list of all directories (and subdirectories) after the installation (`tree` possibly?).
- Here is the difference between 1 and 2 (`diff` possibly?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why not just install from [apt.postgresql.org](http://apt.postgresql.org/)?

---

If you're installing from source, don't bother with `make uninstall`.

PostgreSQL installs everything inside a single directory tree, which is specified with `--prefix` to `configure`. Use a unique prefix that doesn't yet contain anything. That way if you want to remove the PostgreSQL install, you just delete that directory and all its contents.

I usually:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/postgresql94
sudo chown $USER /opt/postgresql94
./configure --prefix=/opt/postgresql94
make
make -C contrib
make install
make -C contrib install
```

This lets me install without having to run a `Makefile` as root.

If I want to delete it I just `sudo rm -r /opt/postgresql94`.

To use the binaries installed I either:

```
export PATH=/opt/postgresql94/bin:$PATH
```

or add that to my `.bash_profile`.

You can just run the binaries directly, e.g.

```
/opt/postgresql94/bin/psql
```

but *this won't work for `initdb` and `pg_ctl`* so it's not that useful in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *inotify* and *dnotify* is the way to go...:

https://lwn.net/Articles/604686/

This in not the easiest way of watching filesystem activities - but its the lowest level that is reachable for the user that is scriptable - from my opinion.

escpeacially the `fschange` command is helpful. according to

http://stefan.buettcher.org/cs/fschange/index.html

the supported watchable commands are:

```
The event types supported by fschange are:

    MOUNT device mountpoint   (when a new file system is mounted)
    UMOUNT mountpoint   (when a file system is unmounted)
    UMOUNT_REQ mountpoint   (when umount has been called but failed due to file system activity, i.e. open files etc.)
    WRITE filename from to   (after a file has been changed and closed; the latter is important because it helps us reduce the number of events generated)
    TRUNCATE filename newfilesize   (after a successful call to truncate)
    RENAME oldpath newpath   (after a file or directory has been renamed or moved)
    UNLINK filename   (when a file has been removed)
    CHMOD filename newfilemode
    CHOWN filename newuser newgroup
    CREATE filename   (after a new file has been created)
    MKDIR dirname
    RMDIR dirname
```

perhaps this is it...